# code combination of @componentscan and lazyinit

Tags: java

- How to use lazyinit in `@componentscan` reference code ?
- How to load one single method as lazy loading ?

I want to load a particular method as lazy in between many methods.how can i achieve that.
`default-lazy-init="true"` without this how can i get lazy loading .
 i want reference code by using

```
@Configuration
@Lazy
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyProject.class, OtherProject.class}lazyinit=true)
public class MyAppConfig {
    ...
}
```

and combination of `@componentscan` and `lazyinit=true`.